# How can I get the appropriate time in a timezone without relying on the server's date?

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

Currently I'm using `strtotime` in PHP to get the timestamp for a particular HH:MM in a timezone.  This has worked beautifully until late-night calculations were necessary.  When the server passes midnight (UTC), `strtotime` starts returning timestamps for the next day, even though in the specified timezone it's still the same day.  What can I do to resolve this?  Thanks!

Here's some relevant code:

```
/* Convert a time (HH:MM) to a localized timestamp */
static function toLocalTime($time, $timezone) {
    switch (strtoupper(trim($timezone))) {
        case 'AST':
        case 'ADT':
            $tz = 'America/Puerto_Rico';
            break;
        case 'EST':
        case 'EDT':
            $tz = 'America/New_York';
            break;
        case 'CST':
        case 'CDT':
            $tz = 'America/Chicago';
            break;
        case 'MST':
            $tz = 'America/Denver';
            break;
        case 'MDT':
            $tz = 'America/Phoenix';
            break;
        case 'PST':
        case 'PDT':
            $tz = 'America/Los_Angeles';
            break;
        case 'AKST':
            $tz = 'America/Los_Angeles';
            break;
        case 'HST':
            $tz = 'Pacific/Honolulu';
            break;
        case 'HDT':
            $tz = 'America/Adak';
            break;
        default:
            Log::error('invalid timezone: ' . $timezone . ' [' . $time . ']');
            return '';
    }

    return strtotime($time . ' ' . $tz);
}
```

Comment: "*Currently I'm using strtotime in PHP to get the timestamp for a particular HH:MM in a timezone.*" — How do you use it? Can you update the question with the relevant code?

Comment: Sure, I have added the code I'm using

Comment: That mapping is not correct (example, `America/Phoenix` could *never* be `MDT`), nor should you try to map time zone abbreviations to time zone names, because there are [just too many ambiguities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone_abbreviations).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the latest online manual entry for [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/strtotime), it appears that it does not take an explicit **timezone** parameter, nor do any of the examples include a timezone. This might cause you problems.